# Rails 3.2 + RELATIVE_URL_ROOT + mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to mount the Rails app into a subdirectory and have mountable engines work too. The app has a Clients resource, the mounted engine is a "Blog".

I've put together a sample app here:

https://github.com/etdsoft/relative_url

Using the `config.ru` method to mount the app:

`map ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
  run RelativeUrl::Application
end`

https://github.com/etdsoft/relative_url/blob/master/config.ru#L10-12

And running the server with:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/app' bundle exec unicorn -p 3001
```

The views contain `debug` traces and it seems that `Rails.application.config.action_controller.relative_url_root` is properly set.

If you browse to:

http://localhost:3001/app/

- The navbar link to Clients doesn't have the "/app" prefix.
- The navbar link to Blog does have it.

Now browse to browse to:

http://localhost:3001/app/clients/

- The navbar link to Clients does have the "/app" prefix.
- The navbar link to Blog doesn't have it.

And finally browse to browse to:

http://localhost:3001/app/admin/blog/

- The navbar link to Clients doesn't have the "/app" prefix.
- The navbar link to Blog does have it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [tests for this feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/test/dispatch/prefix_generation_test.rb), add `RelativeUrl::Application.routes.default_url_options = { script_name: config.action_controller.relative_url_root }` to your configs in the `config/application.rb` file.